# Typescript not warning about optional properties passed to a function

Tags: typescript

Why isn't typescript complaining about this? Is it supposed to?

```
type A = { b?: string };
const a: A = {};

const fn = (b: string) => console.log(b);
fn(a.b);
```

Similarly, this should surely fail:

```
type B = { c: string };
type A = { b?: B };
const a: A = {};
      
const fn = (b: string) => console.log(b);
fn(a.b.c);
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "incremental": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "strictBindCallApply": false,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
      "esModuleInterop": true
   }
}
```

This project uses Typescript 4.6.2

Comment: No `"strict": true`? Why not? Looks like the few type checking options you have mentioned are all `false`.  Maybe turn on at least `strictNullChecks`?

Comment: it's an error. I'm not sure which version fixed it, but versions `5.x` and above give the error

Answer (score 0):

Setting `"strictNullChecks": true` in `tsconfig.json` gets typescript to show the expected errors (as noted in comment by @jcalz - thanks)